# Why the object wrapper by unique_ptr not destroyed after assign it to a map?

Tags: c++

The MSDN said the unique_ptr could not be copied, so if I assign a unique_ptr object to a map like following, the object inside should be destroyed...

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct STest
{
    ~STest() {
        nID = 10;
    }

    int nID;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<STest> > setp;
    setp[0] = std::make_unique<STest>();    // Object should be destroyed, but it is not.
    setp[0]->nID = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, but it can be moved from.

Comment: Also, why do you think the object was not destroyed? It should be, but I don't see anything here that proves it wasn't.

Comment: Because std::make_unqiue returns a r-value reference...

Comment: No. `std::make_unqiue` returns by value.

Answer (score 1):

`std_unique_ptr` cannot be *copied*, but it can be *moved*.  Assigning one `std::unique_ptr` to another *moves* ownership of the object pointer if the source is an *rvalue*.

[std::unique_ptr::operator=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D)

> **Transfers ownership** from `r` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(r.release())` followed by an assignment of `get_deleter()` from `std::forward<E>(r.get_deleter())`.
>
> ...
>
> Note that unique_ptr's assignment operator **only accepts rvalues**, which are typically generated by std::move. (The unique_ptr class explicitly deletes its lvalue copy constructor and lvalue assignment operator.)

So, in your case, you assign a temp object (rvalue) returned by `std::make_shared()` to a `std::unique_ptr` in the `std::map`, so it is safe to transfer ownership of the object pointer.

If you tried using a variable (lvalue) instead, the assignment should not compile.

```
std::unique_ptr<STest> p = std::make_unique<STest>();
setp[0] = p; // <-- error!
```